# how to get options passed before ruby executable?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

suppose this command:

```
FOO=bar BAR=foo executable --args
```

when `executable` is a bash script i just get opts by names, $FOO, $BAR etc.

how to get them if `executable` is a ruby script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "options" are environment variables and, therefore, they are available through `ENV`. Try this:

```
puts ENV['FOO'] # => bar
```